# Error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist (Java 11)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, jaxb, osgi

I am migrating an Ant OSGI Java project from Java 8 to 11.

I have added the following jars:

```
 jakarta.xml.bind-api;bundle-version="4.0.0",
 com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-impl;bundle-version="4.0.0",
 jakarta.activation-api;bundle-version="2.1.0",
 com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-osgi;bundle-version="4.0.0",
 org.glassfish.hk2.osgi-resource-locator;bundle-version="2.5.0"
```

However at BuildFile I am still getting the `error: package jakarta.xml.bind.annotation does not exist`

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: Because the project was composed of several projects, I found that I needed to build one of the projects separately first.